# How do you programmatically create a list using an excel spreadsheet?

Tags: 2010, list, import

I have an excel spreadsheet that I would like to use as data for a SharePoint 2010 list. I know how to do this without code, but for this particular task, I need a coded solution.

Does anyone know how to create a SharePoint 2010 list and populate the list with items from an excel spreadsheet? Here is what I have so far:

```
using (SPSite site = new SPSite(@"http://sitecollection/"))
        {
            SPWeb web = site.RootWeb;
            Guid listGuid = web.Lists.Add("List Title", "List Description", SPListTemplateType.GenericList);
        }
```

Now how do I add the SPListItems that are populated using the excel spreadsheet?

Comment: Where is the excel spreadsheet? Uploaded into a document library? Where is this code running? From VS on the server directly? or as part of something like a workflow?

Comment: This code is running from Visual Studio on the server directly. The spreadsheet is on the hard drive but could easily be uploaded to a document library. This is not part of a workflow

Answer (score 2):

You may need to use the Office COM Interop libraries to access the Excel file, pull the necessary data, and save it to the appropriate list columns. That's what I've used in the past for Excel automation. Let me give you some resources to get started.

## The Class Library

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.excel%28v=office.14%29.aspx

## Some Code Examples

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173186%28v=vs.80%29.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264733%28VS.100%29.aspx

http://www.dotnetperls.com/excel

But remember, these are interface wrappers around COM objects, so you need to explicitly clean up your code:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/158706/how-to-properly-clean-up-excel-interop-objects-in-c-sharp

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vsto/thread/b6e8a28c-6760-4e86-a1aa-e2ce9ec36380 has all of the information you need to pull the excel values and then it is a simple matter of cycling through each row and using something similar to the below

```
SPListItem myItem = myList.Add();
myItem["Field1"] = value1;
myItem["Field2"] = value2;
//etc....

myItem.Update();
```

Answer (score 0):

I've recommended this before, but we have had pretty good luck with [NPOI](http://npoi.codeplex.com/). It works best when the excel file is **simple**.

NPOI basically gives you the API to iterate over the excel file and then you'd just call SharePoint's API to create a list, columns, and then items.

A quick search also revealed this codeplex project: http://spreadsheet2splist.codeplex.com/. I haven't used it so I'm not sure if it will work for your situation.